# How to change request headers

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

How do I set *request headers*? I am downloading image from instagram and I want to change its filename, get the file size. These many request headers are there [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

This is what I have done until now

```
import requests   
@app.route('/try')
def trial():
    img = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'
    imgData = requests.get(img)
    return imgData        # this gives me error: Response object is not callable
```

**Edit** : I want to set the content-disposition header . Another question : when I set the headers, then how would I give the image to the client side?

I read on Internet that to send the file to client side I should set the request header. But how do I send the file is my another question? Sorry for asking another question in the same

Comment: You needed to be clearer in your question; your sample code was missing the Flask request handler (`@app.route()` decorator plus corresponding function). Be *complete* in your problem description: *I'm trying to download an image using `requests`, then serving it with Flask*, then include a minimal Flask app that demonstrates how far you got.

Answer (score 1):

The query which you asked has nothing to do with Flask. Flask is a web framework. Requests is a HTTP library which will help solve your issue

You just need to create a dict with your headers (key: value pairs where the key is the name of the header and the value is, well, the value of the pair) and pass that dict to the headers parameter on the `.get` or `.post` method.

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.get('http://example.com', headers=headers)
```

If you wish to check the header values set when the request was sent then you can simple do this:

```
print r.headers
print r.headers['Content-Type']  # Output - 'text/html'
```

Comment: Note that the request headers don't tell you anything about the response filesize or filename..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - You are right. OP's question is not clear. But check the edit to the question. Especially the last line.

Comment: It's clear that... He want's `file name` and `file size` and based on my answer OP edited like that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = requests.get('https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/e35/12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg')

resp.headers
```

And you will get the response like this ..

```
{'content-length': '73921', 'last-modified': 'Fri, 30 Oct 2015 15:18:29 GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'cache-control': 'max-age=1209600', 'date': 'Wed, 18 Nov 2015 08:44:15 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'image/jpeg', 'timing-allow-origin': '*'}
```

You can get headers... check out the `content-length`. And you will not gonna get the file name I believe because `content-disposition` will not be there. So try something else to get the file name.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. Can I set the `content-disposition` header?

Comment: @sap I think we can't that ... because it's upto instagram maybe

Comment: @sap but you can get the filename.. It's in the URL ... right ?

Comment: Please can you checkout the edited question. I want to send the file to client side, so is it possible to do this? How should I go further

Comment: @sap I'm not getting clearly.. first you got the file from instagram. Now you want to send where ?

Comment: I am using flask framework. I want to download the instagram image in client side (where my html, JS ) code will perform download operation on that file. I need to set the request header from server side and with client side request I will get the file.Did you got now what I am trying to do?

Comment: First you have to download and store into your db and your file system... then in the client side request the file from your server on that time you can set `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME` .. Got it ?